# How to remove search box in ng-select

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

My Angular 5 app needs to remove search box and clear x icon from ng-select.

```
<ng-select [(ngModel)]="model" (change)="onChange($event)">
    <section *ngFor="let x of userList;">
        <ng-option value="{{x.id}}">
              {{ x.name }}
        </ng-option>
    </section>
</ng-select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: We are not here to code for you. Show us what you've done so far so we can help you out finding the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **searchable** and **clearable**

```
 <ng-select [(ngModel)]="model" [searchable]="false" [clearable]="false" (change)="onChange($event)">
        <section *ngFor="let i of list;">
            <ng-option value="{{i.id}}">
                  {{ i.name }}
            </ng-option>
        </section>
    </ng-select>
```